# retrieve specific table data with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Here is the schema of the table I need to scrape some data from. I am using html dom parser. I can retrieve data from each table data with the script I have just written, but I cannot figure out how to get data from just second and third  i.e. proxyip and proxyport, and list them as 'proxyip:proxyport' format.

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        data
    </td>

    <td>
        <span>
            proxyip
        </span>
    </td>

    <td>poxyport</td>

    <td>data</td>

    <td>data</td>

    <td>data</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

My script

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://domain.com/');


foreach($html->find('tr') as $e)
{
  foreach($e->find('td') as $d)
  {
    echo $d->innertext . '<br>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
       $table =$html->find('table',0) ; // Getting the table from scraped HTML content

//For each row, echo 2nd and 3rd td

    foreach($table->find('tr') as $key=>$value) {
       echo  trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',1)->plaintext)).":".trim(strip_tags($value->find('td',2)->plaintext));

        }
```